# How to send model from View to bool method with AJAX in MVC ASP.NET

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to send model from BeginForm to some bool method in Controller.
And if bool method return TRUE = refresh partial (by AJAX) 
else return FALSE = display pop-up with information from method why is false.

Here what i have:

```
PartialView with beginform:
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ItemsList.FirstOrDefault().Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ItemsList.FirstOrDefault().Value)
        </th>
    </tr>

     @foreach (var item in Model.ItemsList)
    {
        using (Html.BeginForm("BuyItem", "Items", FormMethod.Post))
        {
        <tr>
        <td>
             @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
             @Html.Hidden("Name", item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
             @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Value)
             @Html.Hidden("Value", item.Value)
        </td>
        <td>
        <button id="sellButton" onclick="sendRequest(@item)">Buy</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Main view:

```
    <div id="itemsTable">
        Loading data...
    </div>


    @section scripts {
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function WebService() {
            // [...] here is magic to display default data in <div id="itemsTable"> (PartialView)
             }

            function sendRequest(item) {
                if (confirm('Are you sure?')) {
                    var request =
                    {
                        "item": item
                    };
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '/Items/BuyItem',
                        data: JSON.stringify(request),
                        type: 'POST',
                        dataType: "html",
                        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                        error: function (err) {
                            alert('Error: ' + err.statusText);
                        },
                        success: function (result) {
                            $('#itemsTable').html(result);
                        },
                        async: true,
                        processData: false
                    });
                }
            };
        </script>
    }
```

My ItemsController with bool method

```
public bool BuyItem(SomeViewModel model)
    {
        if(test.veryfData(model))
        {
            return true; 
            //refresh data on partialview
            //
            // maybe something like this (but this is bool not ActionResult):
            // return RedirectToAction("_PartialView", "Items", null);
        }
        else
        {
            return false; // Display pop-up with information: "FAIL! Becuase method veryfData found error"
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Ajax.BeginForm and use its OnSuccess & OnFailure methods. Example:

```
   @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Edit", "Case", new AjaxOptions
    {
     HttpMethod = "POST",
     OnSuccess = "getresult",
     OnFailure = "getresult"
    }, new { id = "EditCaseForm" }))
    {

    }
```

In Script section:

```
    function getresult(data) {
        // alert the result returned from data
        alert(data.result);
   };
```

Comment: Im not sure what should be here: "// display created case id on form"

Comment: That's just a comment from my code left by mistake. This was an example which displayed how to use AJAX forms and scripts in MVC

Comment: Ok, anyway still I don't know how handle with this in my case

Comment: PartialView with beginform:
<table class="table"> - Can be replaced with Ajax.BeginForm, and then you can get the result of BuyItem method and display on screen.